# How do you invert Map<v1, Set<v2>> to Map<v2, Set<v1>> in Java with stream()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Map object `Map<t1, Set<t2>>`, and I want to go into the set and turn `t2` in the sets into the keys of the new map. The original key `t1` will be the new value of the map.
For example, given a map containing two entries

```
{key1: [a, b, c], key2: [c, d]}
```

The resulting map would be

```
{a: [key1], b: [key1], c: [key1, key2], d: [key2]}
```

[ ] denotes Set in the above examples.

Comment: You are right. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java 8:

```
map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue()
                .stream()
                .map(v -> new SimpleEntry<>(v, e.getKey())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toSet())))
```

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

```
Multimaps.asMap(map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(ImmutableSetMultimap.flatteningToImmutableSetMultimap(
                Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream()))
        .inverse())
```

[StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
EntryStream.of(map)
        .flatMapValues(Set::stream)
        .invert()
        .grouping(Collectors.toSet())
```

Comment: The Java8 version of the code, gives "Duplicate key Key2" exception with the given data in the question.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be :

```
private static <T1,T2> Map<T1, Set<T2>> invertMap(Map<T2, Set<T1>> data) {
        Map<T1, Set<T2>> output = data.entrySet().stream().collect(() -> new HashMap<T1, Set<T2>>(),
                (mapLeft, leftEntry) -> {
                    for (T1 i : leftEntry.getValue()) {

                        Set<T2> values = mapLeft.get(i);
                        if (values == null)
                            values = new HashSet<>();

                        values.add(leftEntry.getKey());
                        mapLeft.put(i, values);
                    }
                }, (mapLeft, mapRight) -> mapLeft.putAll(mapRight));
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it could be -

```
Map<V1,Set<V2>> inputHashMap = new HashMap<>(); // initialized with your input
Map<V2,Set<V1>> outputHashMap = new HashMap<>();

inputHashMap.forEach((val, keys) -> keys.forEach(key -> {
    if (outputHashMap.containsKey(key)) {
        outputHashMap.get(key).add(val);
    } else {
        outputHashMap.put(key, new HashSet<>() {{
            add(val);
        }});
    }
}));
```

Comment: OP asked for streams; this is basically just a nested loop. Either way, you could make the middle much cleaner: `Set<V1> values = outputHashMap.get(key); if (values == null) outputHashMap.put(key, values = new HashSet<>()); values.add(val);`

Comment: @shmosel Ya missed the `steam()` part of the question statement. Also didn't want to initialize `Set<V1> values` within the loop hence the current solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using stream (might be good for parallel processing using `parallel()` on stream)

```
Map<String, Set<String>> inMap = new HashMap<>();
inMap.put("key1", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")));
inMap.put("key2", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("c", "d")));

Map<String, Set<String>> outMap = inMap.entrySet().stream().collect(
    HashMap::new,
    (m, e) -> e.getValue().forEach(v -> m.computeIfAbsent(v, ignore -> new HashSet<>())
                                         .add(e.getKey())),
    (m1, m2) -> m2.forEach((key, value) -> m1.merge(key, value,
                                           (s1, s2) -> { s1.addAll(s2); return s1; })));

System.out.println(outMap);
// {a=[key1], b=[key1], c=[key1, key2], d=[key2]}
```

Of course old school `for` loop is much  more cleaner

```
Map<String, Set<String>> outMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Entry<String, Set<String>> e : inMap.entrySet())
  for (String v : e.getValue())
    outMap.computeIfAbsent(v, key -> new HashSet<>()).add(e.getKey());
```

Less LOC

```
Map<String, Set<String>> outMap = new HashMap<>();
inMap.forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach(e ->
  outMap.computeIfAbsent(e, __ -> new HashSet<>()).add(k)));
```